# Should I convert DAL.cs into .dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

I 'm doing an application in 3-Tier architecture.I have Data Access Layer(DAL) as Dal.cs file. 
Should I convert the .cs file into .ddl ? 
Why do we need to Create .ddl ? 
Why can't we use Dal.cs itself?
This question raised when I discuss with my friend .He said he is use .dll file instead of .cs . Any Performance Issues?

Comment: What kind of functions and how many do you have in the dal file

Comment: If you make it a project you don't need to recompile all if you make changes at the DAL only. The same is true if you make changes to the DAL but you only want to update changes in your ASP.NET project.

Comment: @Kimtho6 ConnectionStrings and 8 methods to communicate database

Comment: Another reason is reusability. You could use the DAL in other projects. If it's part of the asp.net webapp  you have to copy-paste the code and you always have to remember that you have to maintain two areas.

Comment: It depents on the size of the project. if you only have 8 functions and your sure that you are not going to make alot more. I guess its fine

Comment: Reusability? Sorry Not Clear. Instead of Copy paste .ddl in to my new Project  we can copy paste the .cs file. @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Kimtho6  I'm sure I don't have any changes on that.That's the maximum required function in DAL.cs